# Google Scripts - "If" comparison not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to protect the document from other users if a date in Column `B1 + 2days` is greater than `today`.

I had no problem with protection part, but I can't get the IF statements to work for some weird reason I can't understand.

This is the script where i compare dates:

```
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
send_date = ss.getRange("B1").getValue();
  limit = new Date(send_date.setDate(send_date.getDate()-2))
  limit.setHours(0,0,0,0)
  day0 = new Date();
  day0.setHours(0,0,0,0)
  ss.getRange("D1").setValue(day0);
  ss.getRange("D2").setValue(limit);
  ss.getRange("D3").setValue(limit>day0);
  ss.getRange("D4").setValue(limit<=day0);
  if (day0>limit) { ss.getRange("C1").setValue("can be edited");}
  else if (day0<=limit) { ss.getRange("C1").setValue("cannot be edited");}
```

I set hours/minutes/seconds etc to 0 because I only need to compare the dates day by day.

What happens after I run the script?

For example, `if B1 = '2017-10-24'`, D1 sets to today ('2017-10-26'), D2 sets to ('2017-10-22').

D3, with `limit>day0` comparison gets value `FALSE`, D4 `limit<=day0` gets `TRUE`.

So far so good, but when it comes to IF statements, it seems that these comparisons are reversed.

In this example, C1 is set to 'can be edited'.

For me, that means that first comparison return `FALSE`, the second returned `TRUE`.

When I set date to a date in future (i.e. '2017-10-30'), D1-D4 fields get the right values, but C1 is set to 'cannot be edited'.

I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *not* compare two objects (`day0` and `limit`) like that.

But, you can compare a value of those two objects. For example, using `getTime()`.

```
var day0Time = day0.getTime();
var limitTime = limit.getTime();
if (day0Time > limitTime) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I replaced day0 and limit with .getTime() values, but it still doesn't work.
What grinds me is that even if i couldn't compare dates like that, condition in setValue works correctly (return TRUE) while the same condition in IF works the other way around.

Comment: Something else may be wrong then. Dump to console the values of `*.getTime()` before the `if` statement.

Comment: When B1 is '2017-10-24, .getTime() returns 1508968800000
current date is  1508623200000

Comment: That is a diff of 4 days exactly, so yer, problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I think i found the solution myself. It works fine. Just the order of variables in if condition was wrong. Anyway, thanks for helping figuring this somehow out.